# Java SWT: Disable focus to 1st window until 2nd window closed

Tags: java, window, focus, swt

With SWT, I have 2 windows (in this case, called win1 & win2). win1 is the primary window, and it has a button that opens win2. When I press it, win2 appears and the focus is shifted to it.
I don't want the user to be able to interact with win1 until they exit out of win2. How do I go about this? Basically, I want to 'lock' win1 until win2 is closed.

Using Java 1.7 with Eclipse Kepler and WindowBuilder plugin.

Comment: It's called a "modal" window. It's set as a flag on the Shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
win2 = new Shell(win1, SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL)
```

plus any other flags you are already using for the subordinate window.